# Dúvida com sessions JavaEE

Tags: java, java-ee, session, servlet

É possível obter uma lista com as *sessions* abertas? Não a quantidade (*sessionlistener*), mas as próprias *sessions* para que eu encontre valores em seus atributos.

Comment: Eu até tentei melhorar, mas ainda assim espero que lacônia da pergunta não a impeça de permanecer aberta.

Comment: @user18511, até onde vai meu conhecimento não há nenhuma maneira direta de obter todas as sessões abertas, pelo menos não com a API *standard* (dependendo do seu container / servidor de aplicação isso pode ser possível através de JMX / APIs internas). Dito isso, nada te impede de usar um `SessionListener` para alimentar um [ConcurrentMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) ou algo do gênero com as `sesisons` ativas.

Answer (score 1):

Não tem nada específico na API para isso, como já comentado pelo Anthony. Acho que a razão é bem simples: seria uma falha enorme na segurança.

Existe como você armazenar informações compartilhadas de **aplicação**, que é um valor global invés de uma **session**, que é um contexto por usuário.

A regra é: compartilhe na session o que é individual, crie variáveis de aplicação para aquilo que for compartilhado.